# Batch delete documents of a subcollection error: TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to batch delete a document of a subcollection.

There are times when I might need to delete the same product document ID and different history document ID or multiple product document IDs and different history document IDs.

I am passing the product document ID and history document ID, and I already see them in the console. However, I receive this error once I try to `batch.delete()`
this:

This is what the `docID` and the `historyId` shows in the console:

[image]

```
import {
  doc,
  getDoc,
  updateDoc,
  deleteField,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  addDoc,
  increment,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../Firebase/utilities";

async function deleteDocumentSubcollection(docID, historyId) {
try {
  const batch = writeBatch(db);

//I think this is where the error appears
  historyId.forEach((id) => {
    batch.delete(doc(db, "products", docID, "history", historyId));
  });

  await batch.commit();
  alert("deleted");
 

  console.log("deleted");
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
}
```

**package.json**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), the `docId` and `historyId` should corresponds to the specific Ids of documents. You can try to delete specific documents using their corresponding IDs, and just a note, IDs should not be array:

```
historyId.forEach((id) => {
    batch.delete(doc(db, "products", "documentId", "history", id));
});
```

Comment: I tried deleting it but not with `batch.delete` and used a `deleteDoc`, it works, but if I use the `batch.delete`, the same error still appears

Comment: Can you provide your `package.json` file, and also include in your code the `imports` that you've used in your provided code snippet.

Comment: added it in the post

Comment: Is it right that you didn't include `writeBatch` in your `import` statement? And, your error `n.indexOf is not a function` typically means you're calling a function with some illegal or invalid reference. Lastly, have you tried deleting a specific `document` by specifying which `docId` you need to delete?

Comment: it still won't delete with the writeBatch. I tried deleting a specific document, and it works